# Why do divisions not work in jsonpath-ng?

Tags: python, parsing, jsonpath, arithmetic-expressions, jsonpath-ng

[Jsonpath-ng](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/) offers basic arithmetic as in:

```py
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

jsonpath_expr = parse('$.foo * 2')
target = {'foo': 2}
result = jsonpath_expr.find(target)
result = [match.value for match in result]
print(result)
```

result: `[4]`

However, if I change the expression to `$.foo / 2`, then I get a Parse Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    jsonpath_expr = parse('$.foo / 2')
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jsonpath_ng\ext\parser.py", line 172, in parse
    return ExtentedJsonPathParser(debug=debug).parse(path)
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jsonpath_ng\parser.py", line 32, in parse
    return self.parse_token_stream(lexer.tokenize(string))
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jsonpath_ng\parser.py", line 55, in parse_token_stream
    return new_parser.parse(lexer = IteratorToTokenStream(token_iterator))
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ply\yacc.py", line 333, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ply\yacc.py", line 1201, in parseopt_notrack
    tok = call_errorfunc(self.errorfunc, errtoken, self)
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ply\yacc.py", line 192, in call_errorfunc
    r = errorfunc(token)
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jsonpath_ng\parser.py", line 69, in p_error
    raise Exception('Parse error at %s:%s near token %s (%s)' % (t.lineno, t.col, t.value, t.type))
Exception: Parse error at 1:6 near token / (SORT_DIRECTION)
```

I can sometimes work around this issue by dividing by the inverse value, so I would do `$.foo * 0.5` to get the result `[1.0]`. But this doesn't work if both sides of the equation are numeric values of different types (int or float). So `2 * 0.5` and `0.5 * 2` will result in a Parse error, but `2.0 * 0.5` will not.

How do I get divisions to work? And why can I not multiply a float by an integer?

Comment: I didn't find any test including `/` in the project. It might be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Those are both grammar bugs.

1. Extended JSON paths are allowed to be suffixed with a bracketed expression containing a list of "sorts"; each sort starts with `/` or `\`. To make that work, the extended lexer recognises those two symbols as the token `SORT_DIRECTION`, which takes precedence over the recognition of `/` as an arithmetic operator. Consequently the use of `/` as an arithmetic operator is not allowed by the parser. (In fact, the problem goes deeper than that, but that's the essence.)
2. For some reason, the grammar author chose to separate `NUMBER` (actually, integer) and `FLOAT` in arithmetic expressions, which means that they had to enumerate the possible combinations. What they chose was:

   ```
   jsonpath : NUMBER operator NUMBER
            | FLOAT operator FLOAT
            | ID operator ID
            | NUMBER operator jsonpath
            | FLOAT operator jsonpath
            | jsonpath operator NUMBER
            | jsonpath operator FLOAT
            | jsonpath operator jsonpath
   ```

   There are other problems with this grammar, but the essence here is that it permits `NUMBER operator NUMBER` and `FLOAT operator FLOAT` but does not permit `NUMBER operator FLOAT` or `FLOAT operator NUMBER`, which is what you observe. However, path expressions can work with either `NUMBER` or `FLOAT`.

Comment: Ok so as a dirty fix, I could fork the library and replace the division operator by an unused symbol? (And for 2., I could just add `NUMBER operator FLOAT` and vice versa)

Comment: @EzPizza: Sure, and then you could try to fight the rest of the grammar bugs :-) (For example, operator precedence doesn't work at all; the way the grammar is built suppresses conflict warnings, and there are 50 of them.)

Comment: @EzPizza:  I made a small attempt to fix the grammar errors, but I had to stop because I don't really know what the goal is, and there's a lot of potential ambiguities. Do you happen to have the desired syntax handy?

Comment: That's awesome! All I really need is for something like `$.x / $.y` to work. I don't think adding operator precedence would make sense unless brackets were supported, right?

Comment: @EzPizza: I would expect `2 * $.x + 3` and `$.x * 2 + 3` to the same, because `*` has precedence over `+` (usually). But jsonpath_ng's extended parser grammar doesn't implement precedence (because of a grammar bug; it was intended to do so) and it parses all expressions right to left (again, bug). So those would be respectively `2 * ($.x + 3)` and `$.x * (2 + 3)`, which I suspect would be confusing. As a result, `2 * $.x + 3.0` parses and `$.x * 2 + 3.0` fails. (Interaction between two grammar bugs.) So I'd say the grammar is fundamentally unusable. It could be fixed, but it would be a chore.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the term "grammar bug". Is this a problem with the specifications?

Comment: @ericDuminil: There are no specifications that I know of for the extended syntax implemented by the jsongraph-ng package. But it's written with Ply, which takes a grammar and produces a parser. And the grammar has obvious errors which produce unexpected results reported in this question. Those are bugs, to my way of thinking, and they're in the grammar, so I call them grammar bugs.